# How to pass external variables to ngx-datatable-column?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to get access of an external variable "distance" inside of a cell template. Therefore I'm looking for a way to tell the template the variable like this.

I know that the code below can't work, but how can I achieve something like this? Unfortunately, it is no option to enhance the objects of "filteredSkaterlist" with the objects of "distaneList"

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="filteredList">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let distance of distaneList">
        <ngx-datatable-column name="distance">
            <ng-template let-row="row" let-distance="distance" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row | json }}
                {{ distance | json }}
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
    </ng-container>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: I think it should work without `let-distance="distance"`. Can you create a stackblitz for this.

Comment: @Eldar I tried both - with and without, but distance is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution by myself:

```
<ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let distance of distancelist" name="distance" prop="distance">
    <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
        {{ distance.name }}
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template let-skater="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{ skater.name }}
        {{ distance.name }}
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```